# plpy does not print on the postgres log

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers, plpython

I have a plpython trigger function and I'm trying to log something in it to better understand what it does, but I can't manage to print anything on the postgres log file.
I have tried different level of printing (error, info, notice...) but the only one that does something is the `plpy.fatal` function, that raise an exception caught by the `try-except`.

Here an example of my function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.myfunction() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpythonu
AS $$
try:
    plpy.error("log error")
    plpy.info("log info")
    plpy.notice("log notice")
    if TD["event"] != "INSERT":
        return "OK"

    # do other stuff here
 except Exception, ex:
    #plpy.info("f_b_cli_after : %s" % ex)
    return None
$$;
```

Maybe I'm missing some parameter inside the postgresql.conf, this is what I have now configured:

```
log_destination = 'stderr'
logging_collector = on
log_directory = '/var/log/postgresql'
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'
client_min_messages = notice
log_min_messages = info
log_min_error_statement = info
log_statement = 'all'
```

The documentation I have found does not specify anything else and other answers on this subject here just says that `plpy.notice` is equivalent to `raise notice`, so I expected to work fine as it was.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to print the logs by putting on debug:

```
client_min_messages = notice
log_min_messages = info
log_min_error_statement = info
```

But honestly I don't know if all three are needed or just one of them.

Answer (score -1):

`plpy.info` will create an `INFO` message, `plpy.notice` a `NOTICE` message, and do on. Both `INFO` and `NOTICE` are messages intended for the client, not the log file, so they won't get logged (unless you change `log_min_messages`).

If you want to write a log entry, call `plpy.log`.

With your settings (which I wouldn't recommend) you will get `INFO` and `NOTICE` logged. So if you don't see any log messages, you either didn't reload PostgreSQL after editing the configuration, or you edited the wrong configuration file, or you are looking at the wrong log file.